# How to go about making audio units since Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, core-audio, audiounit

I noticed since Xcode 4.3, the audio unit templates are gone and the audio unit headers and helper apps are a separate download from Apple's website.

I have no idea what to do with the downloaded folder... I tried putting AU Lab And HALLab in Xcode.app/Applications and they don't show up in the new developer tools menu; I tried placing the CoreAudio folder with the headers in Xcode.app/Developer and even recreating /Developer in my root and Xcode doesn't see AUEffectBase.h anywhere (unless I actually add the file).

I saw someone's post on how to come up with a new from-scratch template but I won't even go there yet since Xcode doesn't even find the headers right now.

Any ideas on how to go about making it all work again? 
And about the templates.. I can forget about them right, meaning, the ones we used to have from Apple?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in your project, and referenced by Xcode, then you will have to update those project references. Xcode may refer to them as absolute path, relative to project, relative to SDK and a few others.

At this point, you might consider creating a static library for these dependencies, if you have multiple AUs to build out. Then you just create a static lib to link to, rather than managing a handful of sources per AU.

Templates: It appears they have been removed (temporary? permanent? idk). I moved off distributed template dependence years ago. Perhaps you can scan or hit the CA-API list and see if a dev has one handy.

Comment: for now I'm just changing the rez / include paths.. but yeah, I'll probably end up putting it all into a static lib. Thanks!